# How to count posts that each hashtag has in django queryset

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm, django-queryset

```
class Post(models.Model):     
    post_uuid=models.UUIDField(
    default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    language = models.ForeignKey(
        Languages, default=2, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_post_language = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=400, null=True, blank=True)
    hash_tag = models.ManyToManyField('HashtagName', through='Hashtag', related_name='hash_tag', blank=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.post.id)
```

```
class HashtagName(models.Model):
    Hashtagname = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    hashtag_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=False, unique=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.hashtag_name
```

```
class Hashtag(models.Model):
    hashtag_uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    tag_name = models.ForeignKey(HashtagName,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    posts = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)   
    def __str__(self):
        return self.hashtag_uuid
```

I have these classes.
Im making one api to get the list of trending hashtag

What im trying to do is when someone type
#planet

And i have list of these below hashtag

```
    #planetearth Used in 7 posts 
    #planetjuypiter used in 5 posts
    #planetmercury used in 3 posts
```

Etc

That starts with the keyword i have passed from frontend.

So i want to get the list of top 10 hashtag that starts with the keyword I passed from front end and  based on in how many posts they are used.

Im trying this is it the most efficient?

```
hashtaglist = Hashtagname.objects.filter(hashtagname__startswith = passed name). annotate(posts = Count('hashtag').order_by('-posts')[:10]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you write should work, but you made little error. You placed related name 'hash_tag' in Post for hash_tag field, while you trying to annotate Count('hashtag') in Hashtagname queryset. So the correct code will be:

```
hashtaglist = Hashtagname.objects.filter(
    hashtagname__startswith = passed_name)
        .annotate(posts = Count('hash_tag')\
        .order_by('-posts')[:10]
```

if you trying to reach related records you should use related_name of field in related table if it's specified. If it's not specified you can use name of the related table + 'set' (for example post_set).